# How to use KCL or KVL to find the \$V_{AB}\$?

Tags: voltage, thevenin, norton

Find the \$V_{AB}\$

\$V_{AB}=(2\times 10)+(-10)+[(1 \times 5)+(1+2)\times 5]=25V\$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqplap.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now if i want to use KVL or KCL to calculate the \$V_{AB}\$, How should i do after i modify the norton with thevenin like the figure below ?:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgLrfd.png)</sup>

Comment: `How should i do after i modify the newton` Do you mean, "Norton"?

Comment: You already have given the correct answer. Where are you stuck ?

Comment: KCL tells you that 3 A flows through R3, so you know all the necessary voltage differences in the path between B and A

Comment: @Hilmar I mean i want to use the KCL or KVL to find the \$V_{AB}\$ of the second figure,and the second figure is the thevenin equivalent ,which is transformed from the first figure

Comment: @KingDuken oh yes! Norton

Comment: @Chu I want to use the second picture to find the \$V_{AB}\$

Comment: There’s 2 A flowing, so use Ohm’s law to find the voltages across R2 and R3, then to travel from B to A you go: up through 5V; up through 10 V; down through 10 V; up through 20 V. That’s: 5+10-10+20 = 25 V

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use the second picture to find the \$V_{AB}\$

Here's the second picture.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgLrfd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It is entirely a series circuit, so \$I_1\$ determines the current. Therefore, \$R_2\$ and \$R_3\$ are polarized, as shown, with the voltage drops, as shown:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3ZGwV.png)</sup>

Since \$V_{AB}=V_A-V_B\$, let's just call \$V_B=0\:\text{V}\$. Then \$V_A=V_{AB}\$, by definition. So add up the voltages going from **B** towards **A**: \$\left(V_B=0\:\text{V}\right)+5\:\text{V}+10\:\text{V}-10\:\text{V}+20\:\text{V}=V_A = 25\:\text{V}\$.